# Solving an ODE numerically

Tags: numerical-integration, differential-equations

I really appreciate it if anyone helps me with this:

How can I solve this ODE and plot the answer for $x$ on $[0.6,5]$:

$$
\begin{align*}
-2xy'[x] = y''[x]+ 47.21 (-.0025 x^6 & + 0.0614 x^5- 0.6087 x^4+
3.048 x^3-8.0588 x^2 \\
&  + 10.586 x - 3.9582)^2\operatorname{Erfc}[x]
\end{align*}
$$

With the following boundary conditions:
$y[0.6]=0$  and  $y[\infty]=0$

I used `NDsolve`, but its answer was:

> Cannot find starting value for the variable y'[x]

---

Original source of the equation:

```
-2xy'[x] = y''[x] + 47.21 (-.0025 x^6 + 0.0614 x^5 - 0.6087 x^4 + 3.048 x^3
                          - 8.0588 x^2 + 10.586 x - 3.9582)^2 Erfc[x]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are willing to settle for $y(5) = 0$ instead of $y(\infty) = 0$, the commands to solve it are

```
sol = First@NDSolve[
  {-2 x y'[x] == 47.21` (-3.9582` + 10.586` x - 8.0588` x^2 + 3.048` x^3 - 
         0.6087` x^4 + 0.0614` x^5 - 0.0025` x^6)^2 Erfc[x] + y''[x], 
   y[0.6] == 0, y[5] == 0}, 
   y, {x, 0.6, 5}]


Plot[y[x] /. sol // Evaluate, {x, 0.6, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Increasing the upper bound from 5 to a larger number won't change much, so I believe using $y(5) = 0$ might be a good enough approximation.

There are completely analogous examples in the [`NDSolve` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html).  Please check them.

Comment: @ Szabolcs: thank you so much